# Features for Image containing many objects

Tags: matlab, image-processing, feature-extraction

If I have an image that contains many objects and I want to get for example the first image moments for the entire image as result from `bwlabel`, which is stored in `Ilabel`, how would I do that?

```
[Ilabel num] = bwlabel(Ibw);
stats = regionprops(Ilabel,'BoundingBox');
```

Comment: overflownians maybe? Or better overflowlings? Nah, can't seem to make a good word formation there.

Comment: Do you mean how to access the different entries from stats? For example the Bounding Box coordinates of the 1st object? If so use stats(1).BoundingBox, since stats is a structure. If not please try to clarify a bit what you want. Thanks!

Comment: no i want to take the moment of the whole image .should i take the image without using bwlabel and pass the image directly to regionprops

Comment: Do you want to find the first moments for **each object** in the image, or for **the entire image overall**?  Also, do you want to find the first moment horizontally or vertically?  Refer to the definition of image moments here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment.  You need to be more clear.  We aren't here to guess or read your mind.  You want our help, so you gotta give us more information.

Comment: @Divakar I prefer "overfluvians".

Comment: yes for the entire image overall and I got the vertical and horizontal moments also for each object of the image.I pass the Ilabel array and then another code calculate vertical and horizontal projection for each object then calculate moments from these projections

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Ibw` in your example is **numeric** (not logical) and contains only integers `0` and `1` (or `0` and some other consistent integer value), you should be able to use it directly as a label matrix:

```
stats = regionprops(Ibw,'BoundingBox');
```

This will treat every non-zero pixel in the image as part of a single component. Alternatively , you can take the label matrix from `bwlabel` and change all of the labels to `1`:

```
[Ilabel num] = bwlabel(Ibw);
Ilabel(find(Ilabel)) = 1;
stats = regionprops(Ilabel,'BoundingBox');
```